# Refresh src with jquery and facebox

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, src, facebox

I want to refresh the src of an image, this src is selcected by an iframe thats contents a gallery of photos loaded by facebox, but i  cant make it look this code of the iframe:

```
$('#my_image').on({
        'click': function(){
             var s= $('#my_image').attr('src');
             $('#img').attr('src',s);
         }
     });
```

The `#img` is the src of the image that I want  to refresh with the src of the `#my_image` that is in the gallery.

I´m using php and codeigniter.

I think that the problem is that i cant access the html elements of the original page (not iframe)

Comment: Here is how to access an iframe - http://simple.procoding.net/2008/03/21/how-to-access-iframe-in-jquery/

Comment: I want to use the src selected in the iframe at the original page..